# Perl Program to Print Unicode From Hex Value

Tags: string, perl, unicode, text-rendering

I am starting up with Perl and confused on how to render unicode characters given a hex string variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

foreach my $i (0..10000) {
    my $hex = sprintf("%X", $i);
    print("unicode of $i is \x{$hex}\n");
}
print("\x{2620}\n");
print("\x{BEEF}\n");
```

Gives me the warning: `Illegal hexadecimal digit '$' ignored at perl.pl line 9.`

and no value prints for `\x{$hex}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both [`chr($num)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) and [`pack('W', $num)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) produce a string consisting of the single character with the specified value, just like `"\x{XXXX}"` does.

As such, you can use

```
print("unicode of $i is ".chr(hex($hex))."\n");
```

or just

```
print("unicode of $i is ".chr($i)."\n");
```

---

Note that your program makes no sense without

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Answer (score 4):

Yup.  You can't do that.  No variable interpolation allowed in the middle of a \x like that.  You can use chr() to get that character though.

Answer (score 1):

[Randal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51939895/567650) is correct. For more info, you might want to read [perluniintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html#Creating-Unicode).

From there, you can find, for example:

> At run-time you can use:

```
 use charnames ();
 my $hebrew_alef_from_name
                      = charnames::string_vianame("HEBREW LETTER ALEF");
 my $hebrew_alef_from_code_point = charnames::string_vianame("U+05D0");
```